# Find difference between column X of first row with column Y of second Row

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, numpy

I am very new to pandas,
i have following data set in pandas:

[image]

here i want to find the difference between the upper of first row with lower of second row

in short i want to find difference between
df[0].upper and df[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mum3k.png).lower

i can acheive this by looping through the rows but the data set is huge and i have time constraint. is there any pre-built pandas/numpy function that will help me do this quicker?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`shift(-1)`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.shift.html) and then just subtract

```
df['difference'] = df['upper'] - df['lower'].shift(-1)
```